# RethinkDB error: "Could not bind to http port: The address at localhost:8080 is reserved or already in use."

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm trying to following the ten-minute guide to Rethinkdb by starting the server using the command `rethinkdb` at the command line. However, I get the following error:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ rethinkdb
Running rethinkdb 2.3.5~0xenial (GCC 5.3.1)...
Running on Linux 4.4.0-38-generic x86_64
Loading data from directory /home/kurt/rethinkdb_data
Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
Listening for client driver connections on port 28015
error: Could not bind to http port: The address at localhost:8080 is reserved or already in use.
```

However, as far as I can tell using `netstat` the port is not in use:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ netstat -a | grep 8080
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$
```

I've noticed before that restarting my computer appears to solve this problem, but that is a bit drastic to do every time. How else can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `netstat -nlp`, I was able to determine the process occupying port 8080 and kill it.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the default port of **RethinkDB**:

```
rethinkdb --bind all --http-port 8085
```